# how compare a binary(max) value saved in sql to know is it null, in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, null

I am saving photo in SQL (varbinary(MAX) Data Type) with this code:

```
                    if (SPV1 == true)
                    {
                        imgVC1 = Image.FromFile(Open1.FileName);
                        imgFormat1 = picVisit1.BackgroundImage.RawFormat;
                        Ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                        imgVC1.Save(Ms1, imgFormat1);
                        byte[] ArrayV1 = Ms1.GetBuffer();

                        csCompanies.VisitCard1 = ArrayV1;
                    }
                    else                                                
                        csCompanies.VisitCard1 = null;
```

and it continues with this code in Class:

```
            if(VisitCard1==null)
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitCard1", Convert.ToByte(VisitCard1));
            else
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitCard1", VisitCard1);
```

I Used "If" and "Else" for saving "Null" Value, when user not changed default photo.

Null Data saved as "0x00" in SQL.

When I want show data, i want know that the Data in SQL is Null or not, if is Null, do something, and if not, do something !

But i can't compare Data of SQL with Null value! and when i am using

```
if(cscompanies.Logo1==Null)
```

result always is (False) [that mean its not Null, Even when it Saved as Null  (0x00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse c# null with sql server null. They are different things.

Instead of saving c# null in the database, save DBNull.Value:

```
if(VisitCard1==null)
    com.Parameters.Add("@VisitCard1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = DBNull.Value;
else
   com.Parameters.Add("@VisitCard1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = VisitCard1;
```

Comment: I Used (DBNull.value) insted of (Null) but i meet this error (( Implicit conversion from data type nvarchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.))

Comment: Thanks 4 Ur Answer. Ur code was good 4 Null Value and solved my Problem <3 But when i used Ur code 4 saving Photo , when i wanted to show, i meet this Error ((Buffer cannot be null.))........ Did U Understand me? :D

Comment: This Part: com.Parameters.Add("@VisitCard1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = VisitCard1;       but when i saved with my old code --> ((com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisitCard2", VisitCard2);)) it it was shown without Error

Comment: I've edited my answer once again. Added the missing `Convert.ToByte`.

Comment: Im so sory. Ur Previous Cod Was Correct :D  -->                     com.Parameters.Add("@VisitCard1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = VisitCard1;

Comment: I see. well, in that case, if the answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Comment: is it Necessary that Edit the code to this-->com.Parameters.Add("@VisitCard1", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = VisitCard1                           ??

Comment: but 4 compare the value with Null, what should i do ? :D

Comment: In sql, use `ColumnName IS NULL`

Comment: in C# what should i do ?

Comment: `x == DBNull.Value`

Comment: Error 86 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'System.DBNull'

Comment: Hello Again. Wold you please Help me again for Comparing ?

Comment: I really can't remember, I'll have to test. How are you getting the values back to c#, using a datareader?

Answer (score 0):

For Visit Image i used this plan:

in class :

```
if ((dt.Rows[0]["visitcard1"]) != DBNull.Value)
                    VisitCard1 = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["VisitCard1"];
                else
                    VisitCard1 = null;
```

and in Form:

```
 if (csCompanies.Catalog5 != null)
                {
                    byte[] Array = csCompanies.Catalog5;
                    MS = new MemoryStream(Array);
                    picCata5.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(MS);
                }
```